# Grouping Rows and Defining Column Aggregating Rules

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I'm looking to consolidate multiple rows of differing dtypes in pandas.  I have my `.groupby()` parameter: `['ID']`.  Column `['A']` may repeat values when grouped by `['ID']`, or will differ in data for each row.  Column `['B']` simply needs to be aggregated via `.sum()`.

```
input_df

ID        A        B
140-1    Apple     3.2
140-1    Pear      5.0
143-2    Plum      1.2
143-2    Plum      2.0
```

What is a great way to 1) group by `['ID']`, 2) display value of `['A']` if repeated after grouping, first value of `['A']` if not repeated after grouping, and 3) sum column `['B']` into a new dataframe?

```
output_df

ID        A        B
140-1    Apple     8.2
143-2    Plum      3.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
df.groupby('ID').agg({'A': lambda x: x.unique()[0], 'B': 'sum'}).reset_index()

    ID      A       B
0   140-1   Apple   8.2
1   143-2   Plum    3.2
```

Comment: Your code looks like it would work on any other dataframe.  For some reason, I'm throwing the 'TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed' on my actual working dataframe.

Comment: Can you try this instead? df.groupby('ID').agg({'A': 'first' , 'B': 'sum'}).reset_index()

Comment: I figured it out...the manner in which I was calling the columns was incorrect.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
input_df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda f: pd.DataFrame({'A': f.A.head(1), 'B': f.B.sum()})).reset_index(level=0)


#       ID      A    B
# 0  140-1  Apple  8.2
# 2  143-2   Plum  3.2
```